# how to use php array_search to match 2 key value in multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi dimensional array and i want to use php array_search to find the key for where 2 key values match. below is my array.

```
    $array[] = [
        'id' => 2,
        'title' => 'product 2',
        'size' => 2
    ];

    $array[] = [
        'id' => 2,
        'title' => 'product 2',
        'size' => 1
    ];
$key = array_search(2, array_column($array, 'id'));
```

In the above case i get a `$key` value of `0` but the key value i want to get is `1`. if is possible i want to use  `array_search` to find where `id=>2` and `size=>1` in `$array`.
  Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use foreach?

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if ($row['id'] === 2 && $row['size'] === 1) {
         //found
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't use foreach because i was thinking there was a way but i guess i would have to go with that... thanks for the help